# How to increase internal Application Storage?

Tags: internal-storage

I brought a CHUWI v17HD, which has 8 GB internal storage. But application storage space available is just 1 GB.

I want to increase the size of the internal application storage. How to do so?

Comment: While you cannot increase the size of internal storage (the chip is fixed ;) there might be some other helpful hints. Several of them we've collected in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which you might wish to take a look at.

Comment: As Izzy stated in his comment : you can't change the physical capacity. BUT you can root your device and then use an app such as Link2SD. I will provide links and other necessary information to give you a complete answer when I get home later. I have done this on my LG LS660 (1gb left after purchasing, 5.5gb after FIXING) 16gb SD card. I have multiple games installed (Bard's Tale, Six Guns, and more).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You (probably) can't, but you can [try](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1388996).. if you don't mind potentially bricking your phone. You'll need root.

Comment: You are wrong ,you can mount an ext4 partition on an SD card as /data without bricking your phone but you gonna need root access

Comment: The phone would be bricked possibly because of altering partition boundaries which may disrupt Android booting or functioning, thereby, rendering the device useless, hence bricked.